# BeginEdit in Cell using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, mvvm

I want a GridView to directly switch into edit mode when a new row is added. I cant figure out how to do this without violating the MVVM-Pattern I have to use.

This is how my codes works at the moment.

**XAML:**

```
<RadGridView Name="Table" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
```

**Code-behind:**

```
    public void ViewBeginEdit()
    {
        Table.CurrentCellInfo = new GridViewCellInfo(Table.SelectedItem, Table.Columns["ColName"]);
        Table.Focus();
        Table.BeginEdit();
    }
```

**ViewModel:**

```
    private void ExecuteAddCommand(string name)
    {
        Items.Add(name);
        SelectedItem = name;
        _view.ViewBeginEdit(); // <-- MVVM Violation
    }
```

I can bind `CurrentCellInfo` to the ViewModel but i can't access the Columns Property or the `Focus()` and `BeginEdit()` Methods there (without violating MVVM).

I can't use the `AddingNewDataItem-Event` because the item is not yet added so `Focus()` and `BeginEdit()` wont succeed.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: Well you can try this: In the setter of the list you can put a call for function that will change bool property(EditMode). This bool property should be bind to your cell.

Comment: To initiate something complicated in the View you can use events in ViewModel. View *knows* about `ViewModel`, can subscribe to ViewModel's events and do something in response.

Comment: Events are better than my current solution, so I changed my code to use events. Thank you. But if there was a solution without code behind, that would be even better.

Comment: @user4758246 did you resolve this issue? I have the same problem! Nobody responded to you.